# Getting two navigation bar when using TabBar

Tags: swift

I rewrite a TabBarController:

```
//
//  TabBarController.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Coel on 2019/7/4.
//

import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let TrashListVC = TrashListViewController()
        let SearchVC = SearchViewController()
        let SettingsVC = SettingsViewController()
        TrashListVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .search, tag: 0)
        SearchVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .search, tag: 1)
        SettingsVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 2)
        let tabBarList = [SearchVC, TrashListVC, SettingsVC]
        viewControllers = tabBarList.map {
            UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

And I call this in AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

This result a double Navigation bar like this:

[image]
（Sorry it's in Chinese)
I try to add `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true` in TabBarController.swift but not working.

Answer (score 3):

You are saying

```
window?.rootViewController = 
    UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())
```

So you are wrapping a navigation controller around your tab bar controller.

But then you are saying:

```
    viewControllers = tabBarList.map {
        UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
    }
```

So you are wrapping a navigation controller around every one of your tab bar controller's individual children.

Thus, for every child of the tab bar controller, it has *two* navigation controllers around it, once for each time you see the words "UINavigationController" in the code I've quoted.

So that's why you see two navigation bars. You have a navigation controller inside a navigation controller.

That architecture is incoherent and forbidden. You may not put a navigation controller, at any depth, inside a navigation controller. You need to rethink your entire architecture.

Comment: Making the TabBarController the rootViewController would be a common approach.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! :)

Comment: Yeah. Change the line in your didFinishLaunching to read `window?.rootViewController = TabBarController()`. If you're using a tab bar controller it should be the top-level navigation object in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 navigations one for the main tabBar and the other for every child vc   to hide both of them

1-

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
window?.rootViewController = nav
```

or only

```
window?.rootViewController = TabBarController()
```

2-

```
viewControllers = tabBarList.map { item in 
   let nav =  UINavigationController(rootViewController:item)
   nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
   return nav
}
```